# Loop through table php

Tags: php, html

Below is a while loop from my php script that populates a HTML table. I want the IF statement at the bottom to set the attribute of `<td id="status"></td>` depending on its value. But when I run the code, only the value in the first row is set. 
I guess the problem is with using a single element ID in a loop. Can I use the element ID `"status"` for every row in the table?

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $dd=strtotime($row["due_date"]);
                $dd=Date('d-m-Y',$dd);
                $bd=strtotime($row["borrow_date"]);
                $bd=Date('d-m-Y',$bd);

                echo '
                <tr>
                <td>'.$row["user_email"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["last_name"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["first_name"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["movie_ID"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["title"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["year"].'</td>
                <td>'.$bd.'</td>
                <td>'.$dd.'</td>
                <td id="status"></td>



                </tr>
                ';
                $i++;

                if($dd<$cd){
                    echo' <script type="text/javascript">
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Overdue";
                    </script>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Not Due";
                    </script>';
                }
            }
```

Comment: You cannot use same `id` for multiple elements.

Comment: Use classes instead. e.g. if(true) class="status1" else class="status2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - you **cannot** use same id for multiple elements.

Read function name: `getElementById`. See - `Element`, not `Elements`. That's why using `getElementById` returns you only first element.

Going further - you can check you condition in php (using simple ternary operator, for example) and forget about javascript:

```
    // previous code here
    '<td>'.$dd.'</td>
    <td>' . ($dd<$cd? 'Overdue' : 'Not Due') . '</td>
</tr>';
$i++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do in php itself

```
if($dd<$cd){
      echo '<td>Overdue</td>';  
     }else{
     echo  '<td>Not Due</td>';
    }
```